# Best and easiest way to seal insulation above concrete pour in unfinished areas of basements?

Tags: insulation, basement, foundation, joists

One of the things my crew is doing is trying to quickly make unfinished areas in basements look nicer and easier to clean.

We usually stuff all outer joist walls with roxul to insulate and while this is effective it looks awful.

It isn't easy to hide this either because often the joists are a good 2-3" above the concrete that the insulation is sitting on.

So we either install plywood strips then a strip of 2x4 on the bottom to cover the gap or more common adding a 2x to the joist then a strip of plywood past or to the wall.

Goals here:

1. Looks nice.
2. Keeps insulation from falling or dirt/debris.
3. Wind break - not expecting an air seal at all.
4. Can easily be moved if home owner needs to run pipe/wire (we usually have 2-3 screws per 6' strip)

So is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Pictures might help? I'm not getting a clear idea from the description. Joist walls? Do you mean rim joists?

Answer (score 1):

For a quick cover to make it look better, how about drywall screwed to the studs?  Keep insulation & drywall at least 1" off the floor to keep moisture from wicking into it and add a wide vinyl trim ţo cover the gap.